# Reverse colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how to simply reverse the color order of a given colormap in order to use it with plot_surface.

Answer (score 743, accepted):

The standard colormaps also all have reversed versions. They have the same names with `_r` tacked on to the end. ([Documentation here.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html#reversed-colormaps))

Comment: This does not work with "amfhot" : "ValueError: Colormap amfhot_r is not recognized". I suppose "hot_r" will have to suffice.

Comment: Similarly, "ValueError: Colormap red_r is not recognized."

Comment: In the link provided to the documentation  there is nothing related to reversing colormaps.

Comment: They changed the location in the documentation, I've updated the link.

Comment: `Reds` and `Reds_r`, not `red` and `red_r`, nor `reds` and `reds_r`.

Answer (score 46):

The solution is pretty straightforward. Suppose you want to use the "autumn" colormap scheme. The standard version:

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.autumn
```

To reverse the colormap color spectrum, use get_cmap() function and append '_r' to the colormap title like this:

```
cmap_reversed = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('autumn_r')
```

Comment: could you provide documentation link where you got the .autumn from?

Comment: This may break later... https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html, but I'm sure anyone interested will be able to find this by search anyway.

Comment: Works as of 3.2.2

Answer (score 33):

As of Matplotlib 2.0, there is a `reversed()` method for `ListedColormap` and `LinearSegmentedColorMap` objects, so you can just do

`cmap_reversed = cmap.reversed()`

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html?highlight=reverse#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.reversed) is the documentation.

Comment: this is (in  my opinion) the best answer here, by far

Answer (score 31):

In matplotlib a color map isn't a list, but it contains the list of its colors as `colormap.colors`. And the module `matplotlib.colors` provides a function `ListedColormap()` to generate a color map from a list. So you can reverse any color map by doing

```
colormap_r = ListedColormap(colormap.colors[::-1])
```

Comment: +1. However, this won't generically reverse any colormap. Only `ListedColormap`s (i.e. discrete, rather than interpolated) have a `colors` attribute.  Reversing `LinearSegmentedColormaps` is a bit more complex. (You need to reverse every item in the `_segmentdata` dict.)

Comment: Regarding reversing `LinearSegmentedColormaps`, I just did this for some colourmaps. [Here's an IPython Notebook about it.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/kwinkunks/notebooks/blob/master/Matteo_colourmaps.ipynb)

Comment: @kwinkunks i think the function in your notebook is not right, see answer below

Answer (score 13):

As a `LinearSegmentedColormaps` is based on a dictionary of red, green and blue, it's necessary to reverse each item:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
def reverse_colourmap(cmap, name = 'my_cmap_r'):
    """
    In: 
    cmap, name 
    Out:
    my_cmap_r

    Explanation:
    t[0] goes from 0 to 1
    row i:   x  y0  y1 -> t[0] t[1] t[2]
                   /
                  /
    row i+1: x  y0  y1 -> t[n] t[1] t[2]

    so the inverse should do the same:
    row i+1: x  y1  y0 -> 1-t[0] t[2] t[1]
                   /
                  /
    row i:   x  y1  y0 -> 1-t[n] t[2] t[1]
    """        
    reverse = []
    k = []   

    for key in cmap._segmentdata:    
        k.append(key)
        channel = cmap._segmentdata[key]
        data = []

        for t in channel:                    
            data.append((1-t[0],t[2],t[1]))            
        reverse.append(sorted(data))    

    LinearL = dict(zip(k,reverse))
    my_cmap_r = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(name, LinearL) 
    return my_cmap_r
```

See that it works:

```
my_cmap        
<matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap at 0xd5a0518>

my_cmap_r = reverse_colourmap(my_cmap)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.475, 0.9, 0.15])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap = my_cmap, norm=norm,orientation='horizontal')
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap = my_cmap_r, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

**EDIT**

---

I don't get the comment of user3445587. It works fine on the rainbow colormap:

```
cmap = mpl.cm.jet
cmap_r = reverse_colourmap(cmap)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.475, 0.9, 0.15])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap = cmap, norm=norm,orientation='horizontal')
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap = cmap_r, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

But it especially works nice for custom declared colormaps, as there is not a default `_r` for custom declared colormaps. Following example taken from http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html:

```
cdict1 = {'red':   ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5, 0.0, 0.1),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                   (0.5, 0.1, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
         }

blue_red1 = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('BlueRed1', cdict1)
blue_red1_r = reverse_colourmap(blue_red1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.475, 0.9, 0.15])

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap = blue_red1, norm=norm,orientation='horizontal')
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap = blue_red1_r, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

Comment: This example is not complete in a sense that the segmentdata does not to be in lists so it is not necessaraly reversable (e.g. standard rainbow colormap).
I think in principle all LinearSegmentedColormaps should in princible be reversible using a lambda function as in the rainbow colormap?

Comment: @user3445587 I add some more examples, but I think it works just fine on the standard rainbow colormap

Comment: Since it was too long, I added a new answer, which should work for all kind of LinearSegmentData.  

The problem is that for rainbow, _segmentdata is implemented differently. So your code - at least on my machine - does not work with the rainbow colormap.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way (yet) of reversing arbitrary colormaps, but one simple solution is to actually not modify the colorbar but to create an inverting Normalize object:

```
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

class InvertedNormalize(Normalize):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 1 - super(InvertedNormalize, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can then use this with `plot_surface` and other Matplotlib plotting functions by doing e.g.

```
inverted_norm = InvertedNormalize(vmin=10, vmax=100)
ax.plot_surface(..., cmap=<your colormap>, norm=inverted_norm)
```

This will work with any Matplotlib colormap.

Comment: There is now! https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.reversed

Comment: This is a great answer. It lends itself to all kinds of additional manipulations. I inverted a cyclical colormap from inside out with `(0.5 + super) % 1`. Big up!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of LinearSegmentedColormaps. In some, the _segmentdata is given explicitly, e.g., for jet:

```
>>> cm.jet._segmentdata
{'blue': ((0.0, 0.5, 0.5), (0.11, 1, 1), (0.34, 1, 1), (0.65, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)), 'red': ((0.0, 0, 0), (0.35, 0, 0), (0.66, 1, 1), (0.89, 1, 1), (1, 0.5, 0.5)), 'green': ((0.0, 0, 0), (0.125, 0, 0), (0.375, 1, 1), (0.64, 1, 1), (0.91, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0))}
```

For rainbow, _segmentdata is given as follows:

```
>>> cm.rainbow._segmentdata
{'blue': <function <lambda> at 0x7fac32ac2b70>, 'red': <function <lambda> at 0x7fac32ac7840>, 'green': <function <lambda> at 0x7fac32ac2d08>}
```

We can find the functions in the source of matplotlib, where they are given as

```
_rainbow_data = {
        'red': gfunc[33],   # 33: lambda x: np.abs(2 * x - 0.5),
        'green': gfunc[13], # 13: lambda x: np.sin(x * np.pi),
        'blue': gfunc[10],  # 10: lambda x: np.cos(x * np.pi / 2)
}
```

Everything you want is already done in matplotlib, just call cm.revcmap, which reverses both types of segmentdata, so

```
cm.revcmap(cm.rainbow._segmentdata)
```

should do the job - you can simply create a new LinearSegmentData from that. In revcmap, the reversal of function based SegmentData is done with

```
def _reverser(f):
    def freversed(x):
        return f(1 - x)
    return freversed
```

while the other lists are reversed as usual

```
valnew = [(1.0 - x, y1, y0) for x, y0, y1 in reversed(val)]
```

So actually the whole thing you want, is

```
def reverse_colourmap(cmap, name = 'my_cmap_r'):
     return mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(name, cm.revcmap(cmap._segmentdata))
```