# Set a starting point in a colour scale of a map geo pandas

Tags: colors, maps, geopandas

I have the following map created with:

`gdf1.plot('average', figsize=(12,12), legend=True, cmap='OrRd')`

But I want to set the starting point of the scale to a darker point so the backgroud becomes crearly distinguishible.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279560/reverse-colormap-in-matplotlib) you can just add an _r at the end of the color name and it should work. Try using cmap='OrRd_r'

Comment: It inverted the colors and it looks better, but now the darkest pronvince is completely white... I'm trying to set the color of the zero in the scale a bit darker (where is 0.10 for example).

Comment: You might need to select a different color map. Take a look at this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#list-colormaps) There are some color maps that where the lightest color are darker like copper for example.