# How to reverse the palette of a seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am plotting a scatter plot of price of houses w.r.t latitude and longitude.
**I want to reverse the palette so that the red color depicts the most expensive house.**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.scatterplot(x='long' ,y='lat' ,data=non_top_1_perc ,hue='price' ,edgecolor=None , 
alpha=0.2,palette='RdYlGn' )
```

[Here's the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5gem.png)

Comment: maybe try to pass `cmap=sns.color_palette("Reds")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse colormap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279560/reverse-colormap-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `palette` parameter to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
palette=plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn').reversed()
```

This is using `matplotlibs` function named `get_cmap` which has a reversed option made for this.

Latest test with matplotlib version 3.4.3.

**Output in a JupyterNotebook**

[image: reversed palette]

Comment: It does work, however its reversing the palette to be dominated by green, i.e the less expensive houses are shown in green color ,whereas I wanted it to be shown in yellow.

Comment: If so there are some opportunities: 1. Make a own colormap with the colors you prefere 2. Add a dummy value you plot outside of the visible area

Comment: Thanks -however could you please explain the second point further?

Comment: It is quick and dirty but you can add `plt.xlim(left,right)` and `plt-ylim(bottom, top)`. If you now add a pair of 'lat' and 'long' outside of your limits, you can pass a very low price. This will adjust how the the palette will be used.

Comment: this does not work anymore: `TypeError: 'ListedColormap' object is not iterable`. But there are good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279560/reverse-colormap-in-matplotlib

Comment: @ Ufos I am using matplotlib v3.4.3 and it is still working. Which version do you use?